# Concat String by Group

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework, concatenation

I want to group records by `_id` and create a string by combining `client_id` values.

Here are examples of my documents:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("59e955e633d64c81875bfd2f"),
  "tag_id" : 1,
  "client_id" : "10001"
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("59e955e633d64c81875bfd30"),
  "tag_id" : 1,
  "client_id" : "10002"
}
```

I'd like to have this output:

```
{
  "_id" : 1
  "client_id" : "10001,10002"
}
```

Comment: sorry about the typo, it should group by tag_id

Comment: @HassanImam Hardly a duplicate. The question does specifically ask to "concat string" which is certainly not what your suggested duplicate demonstrates at all.

Comment: @NeilLunn I noticed it and removed the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with the aggregation framework as a "two step" operation. Which is to first accumulate the items to an array via [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) withing a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline, and then to use [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) with [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) on the produced array in final projection:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$tag_id",
    "client_id": { "$push": "$client_id" }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "client_id": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$client_id",
        "initialValue": "",
        "in": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ "$$value", "" ] },
            "then": "$$this",
            "else": {
              "$concat": ["$$value", ",", "$$this"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

We also apply [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) here to avoid concatenating an empty string with a comma in the results, so it looks more like a delimited list.

FYI There is an JIRA issue [SERVER-29339](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29339) which does ask for [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to be implemented as an [accumulator expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/) to allow it's use directly in a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage. Not likely to happen any time soon, but it theoretically would replace [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) in the above and make the operation a single pipeline stage. Sample proposed syntax is on the JIRA issue.

If you don't have [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) ( requires MongoDB 3.4 ) then just post process the cursor:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$tag_id",
    "client_id": { "$push": "$client_id" }
  }},
]).map( doc =>
  Object.assign(
    doc,
   { "client_id": doc.client_id.join(",") }
  )
)
```

Which then leads to the other alternative of doing this using [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) if you really must:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
  function() {
    emit(this.tag_id,this.client_id);
  },
  function(key,values) {
    return [].concat.apply([],values.map(v => v.split(","))).join(",");
  },
  { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Which of course outputs in the specific `mapReduce` form of `_id` and `value` as the set of keys, but it is basically the output.

We use `[].concat.apply([],values.map(...))` because the output of the "reducer" can be a "delimited string" because `mapReduce` works incrementally with large results and therefore output of the reducer can become "input" on another pass. So we need to expect that this can happen and treat it accordingly.

Comment: thank you, it is really useful, i use mongo 3.4, thus the first script works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Starting `Mongo 4.4`, the `$group` stage has a new aggregation operator [`$accumulator`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/accumulator/#accumulator-aggregation) allowing custom accumulations of documents as they get grouped:

```
// { "tag_id" : 1, "client_id" : "10001" }
// { "tag_id" : 1, "client_id" : "10002" }
// { "tag_id" : 2, "client_id" : "9999"  }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: "$tag_id",
    client_id: {
      $accumulator: {
        accumulateArgs: ["$client_id"],
        init: function() { return [] },
        accumulate: function(ids, id) { return ids.concat(id) },
        merge: function(ids1, ids2) { return ids1.concat(ids2) },
        finalize: function(ids) { return ids.join(",") },
        lang: "js"
      }
    }
  }}
])
// { "_id" : 2, "client_id" : "9999" }
// { "_id" : 1, "client_id" : "10001,10002" }
```

The accumulator:

- accumulates on the field `client_id` (`accumulateArgs`)
- is initialised to an empty array (`init`)
- accumulates by concatenating new ids to already seen ids to new ones (`accumulate` and `merge`)
- and finally joins all ids as a string (`finalize`)