# How to use Group By and concat fields as string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am novice at **MongoDB 3.2**,

Consider below example,

```
{ "_id" : "2tLX8ALYfRvbgiurZ", "service" : "GSTR 1" }
{ "_id" : "2tLX8ALYfRvbgiurZ", "service" : "GSTR 2" }
{ "_id" : "2tLX8ALYfRvbgiurZ", "service" : "GSTR 3" }
```

How can I use **Group By** `_id` and create single field with all document fields being concatenated, below is expected output,

```
{ "_id" : "2tLX8ALYfRvbgiurZ", "service" : "GSTR 1, GSTR 2, GSTR 3" }
```

I used below but it gives array,

```
db.getCollection('Clients').aggregate(
      [
        {
            $group : {
             _id : "$_id",
             services :  "$services"
            }
        }
      ]
    ).map( doc =>
      Object.assign(
        doc,
       { "services": doc.services.join(",") }
      )
    );
```

it gives output as

```
[{ "_id" : "2tLX8ALYfRvbgiurZ", "service" : "GSTR 1, GSTR 2, GSTR 3" }]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concat String by Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841825/concat-string-by-group)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate string values in array in a single field in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882552/concatenate-string-values-in-array-in-a-single-field-in-mongodb)

Comment: @dnickless: The implementation in your suggested link is in mongo db 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
docIwant = db.getCollection('Clients').aggregate(
      [
        {
            $group : {
             _id : "$_id",
             services :  "$services"
            }
        }
      ]
    ).map( doc =>
      Object.assign(
        doc,
       { "services": doc.services.join(",") }
      )
    );
return docIwant[0].
```

Comment: `$push` creates array, I need concatenated String.

Comment: I would risk to say that that's not possible using mongodb solo can't be used for this task. I did a fast research in concatenations using projections but I could not find an answer for that. Maybe you could use your favorite programming language to concatenate after the query. If it's in python I can give you a hand.

Comment: @isael.zinc : thanks a lot. I am using javascript :)

Comment: If my answer answered your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 6):

It's working fine i checked

```
db.client.insert([
    { "id" : "2tLX8ALYfRvbgiurZ", "service" : "GSTR 1" },
    { "id" : "2tLX8ALYfRvbgiurZ", "service" : "GSTR 2" },
    { "id" : "2tLX8ALYfRvbgiurZ", "service" : "GSTR 3" }
]);
```

```js
db.getCollection('client').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {
                _id:"$id",
                myfield: {$push: {$concat: ["$service"]}}
            }
        },
        {
            $project:{
                "results": {
                    $reduce: {
                        input: "$myfield",
                        initialValue: '',
                        in: {$concat: ["$$value", ", ", "$$this"]}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: You can also add ` '$cond': [
                  {
                    '$eq': [
                      '$$value', ''
                    ]
                  }, '', ', '
                ]` in the `$concat` to omit any leading ", "