# Mongodb: get distinct records with all columns, and concat value against another column at the same time

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way to get distinct records with all columns, and at the same time, concat against another column. For example I have Records:

```json
{ _id : 611a20dfcfbd65f2fbc4aad8, name : "John", skill: "sql", birth :"2000-07-01" }
{ _id : 611a20dfcfbd65f2fbc4aadb, name : "David",  skill: "java", birth :"1993-06-08" }
{ _id : 611a20dfcfbd65f2fbc4aade, name : "Tom",  skill: "C#", birth :"1990-12-15" }
{ _id : 611a20dfcfbd65f2fbc4aae1, name : "John",  skill: "js", birth :"2000-07-01" }
{ _id : 611a20dfcfbd65f2fbc4aae4, name : "Tom", skill: "sql", birth :"1990-12-15"}
{ _id : 611a20dfcfbd65f2fbc4aae7, name : "John", skill: "java", birth :"2000-07-01" }
```

what I expected is(distinct on `name`, concat on `skill`)

```json
{ name : "John", skill: "sql,js,java", birth :"2000-07-01" }
{ name : "David",  skill: "java", birth :"1993-06-08" }
{ name : "Tom",  skill: "C#,sql", birth :"1990-12-15" }
```

I found some useful answers like:

- [Concat String by Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841825/concat-string-by-group/46842051#46842051)
- [Get distinct records values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655506/get-distinct-records-values/59756228#59756228)

The problem is I can't properly combine them together.

- The `skill` column returns `null` with below query

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$name",
    "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" },
    "skillArray": { "$push": "$skill" },
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": "$doc"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "skill": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$skillArray",
        "initialValue": "",
        "in": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ "$$value", "" ] },
            "then": "$$this",
            "else": {
              "$concat": ["$$value", ",", "$$this"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { $sort: { birth: -1 }}
])
```

[image: the skill column is null]

- Almost make it, but this query returns nested record on each line(just remove `{ "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$doc" }},` section of above example)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$name",
    "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" },
    "skillArray": { "$push": "$skill" },
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "skill": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$skillArray",
        "initialValue": "",
        "in": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ "$$value", "" ] },
            "then": "$$this",
            "else": {
              "$concat": ["$$value", ",", "$$this"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { $sort: { birth: -1 }}
])
```

[image: nested record on each line]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost done, use `$reduce` with `$concat` instead of `$cond`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" },
      skillArray: { $push: "$skill" },    
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "doc.skill": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$skillArray",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $concat: [
              "$$value",
              { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$value", ""] }, "", ", "] },
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$doc" }
  },
  {
    $sort: { birth: -1 }
  }
])
```

Working example:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/V4lrNIWUR29

You can also use [`$replaceWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/) with [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" },
      skillArray: { $push: "$skill" },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $mergeObjects: [
        "$doc",
        {
          skill: {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$skillArray",
              initialValue: "",
              in: {
                $concat: [
                  "$$value",
                  { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$value",""] }, "", ", " ] },
                  "$$this"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { birth: -1 }
  }
])
```

Working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/K-7JUKy4MPS

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works! in fact I just resolved it myself with the inspiration from this answer in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298993/replaceroot-in-mongodb，add `$project` in the end of my second code block OR just like your answer, generate a new column under the root doc --> `doc.skill`  then do the replacing with `$replaceRoot`

Comment: I added a second solution which I think is better than the first one

Comment: I have to say it's a cleaner solution, I expected string instead of Array, though. thanks for your time & kindly reply.

Comment: I forgot about string instead of array, corrected it

Answer (score 0):

The thing is: I don't really understand mongo, The simple truth is:

- **If you create a new field, you must arrange it with other fields in a appropriate level, rather than ignore it.**
- **If you already have a superset of the document you are looking for, you only need to do corresponding mapping, it's enough.**

---

Corrections on the two examples in my question(annotation to the above two conclusions)

1. Add new field under the ROOT doc with `$addFields`, then doing the replacement with `$replaceRoot`(changing made on my first code block: use `doc.skill` instead of `skill`, switch the order of `$addFields` and `$replaceRoot`)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$name",
    "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" },
    "skillArray": { "$push": "$skill" },
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "doc.skill": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$skillArray",
        "initialValue": "",
        "in": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ "$$value", "" ] },
            "then": "$$this",
            "else": {
              "$concat": ["$$value", ",", "$$this"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": "$doc"
  }},
  { $sort: { birth: -1 }}
])
```

2. Create the super document of the required document, then get the sub document with `$project`(changing made on my second code block: just add `$project` section after `$addFields`)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$name",
    "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" },
    "skillArray": { "$push": "$skill" },
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "skill": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$skillArray",
        "initialValue": "",
        "in": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ "$$value", "" ] },
            "then": "$$this",
            "else": {
              "$concat": ["$$value", ",", "$$this"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  {$project: {
    _id: "$doc._id",
    name: "$_id", //or "$doc.name",
    skill:"$skill",
    birth:"$doc.birth",
  }},
  { $sort: { birth: -1 }}
])
```